Cramer-Rao Lower Bound of sinusoid in WGN
From Steven M. Kay's book fundamentals of statistical signal processing, he derives in chapter 3 the CRLB for a single sinusoidal frequency estimation in WGN when the amplitude and phase are known (example 3.5) and the CRLB for a single sinusoidal frequency, amplitude and phase parameters when all three are unknown (example 3.14).
Our model:
$$x[n]=Acos(2\pi f_0n+\phi) + w[n]$$ $$w[n]\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$$$n = 0, 1, ..., N-1$$
The CRLB for the latter case is:
He derives the Fischer information matrix, inverts it and finally gets to the following 3 CRLB:
$$var(\hat{A}) \geq \frac{2\sigma^2}{N}$$
$$var(\hat{f_0}) \geq \frac{12}{(2\pi)^{2}\eta N(N^{2}-1)}$$
$$var(\hat{\phi}) \geq \frac{2(2N-1)}{\eta N(N+1)}$$
$\eta=\frac{A^2}{(2\sigma)^2}$ is the SNR. We see that the variance of the frequency estimator is not dependent on the frequency itself.
For the case where the amplitude and phase are known, he derives the following CRLB:
$$var(\hat{f_0}) \geq \frac{\sigma^2}{A^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}2\pi nsin(2\pi f_{0}n+\phi)}$$
where now the minimal variance is dependent on the frequency itself. Can someone provide some intuition into why it now depends on the actual frequency while for the first case it does not? Also, for a constant (or very, very low frequency) signal ($f_0->0$), we get a CRLB of (almost) infinity, while for the case of estimating all three parameters the variance is bounded. How is it that when attempting to estimate all three parameters, the minimum variance of the frequency is not infinity for constant (very, very low frequency) signals? Does this mean there does'nt exist an unbiased estimator for frequency when phase and amplitude are known?

The first estimation is based on the assumption that "$f_0$ is not near 0 or 1 2, which allows us to make certain simplifications" such as:
$$\frac{1}{N^{i+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}n^i\sin(4\pi f_0n+2\pi)\approx0$$
$$\frac{1}{N^{i+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}n^i\cos(4\pi f_0n+2\pi)\approx0$$
The second estimator does not include this assumption but it is revealed from the final estimator form...

you're right, missed the assumption. what do you think it means that the CRLB is infinity for certain values of f? does it mean that no unbiased estimator exists? if so, doesn't it perhaps make the CRLB useless for such cases?
